# pandas calculate the proportion of sub group

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a pandas.core.series.Series

```
rate         a.status             
(0.0, 0.05]  20          4                
(0.05, 0.1]  20          7
             21          2
             11          1
(0.1, 0.15]  20          2
             21          1
(0.15, 0.2]  20          2
             21          1
(0.3, 0.35]  20          2
(0.35, 0.4]  20          2
(0.45, 0.5]  20          2
(0.55, 0.6]  20          1
(0.6, 0.65]  20          1
```

I want to calculate the proportion of status 20 for every rate,
the result should be

```
rate               proportion
(0.0, 0.05]          1   <----    4/4
(0.05, 0.1]          0.7 <----  7/(7+2+1)

(0.1, 0.15]          0.66 <----  2/(2+1)

(0.15, 0.2]          0.66  <----  2/(2+1)

(0.3, 0.35]         1
(0.35, 0.4]         1
(0.45, 0.5]         1
(0.55, 0.6]         1
(0.6, 0.65]         1
```

I have tried a[a['a.status'] == 20].count() but it does not work.
what should I do?

Comment: Can you post an easy to reproduce dataframe so we can try and help?

Comment: Would you like to show your original df

Answer (score 0):

Reproduction of your test sample:

```
text = """rate         a.status             
(0.0,0.05]  20          4                
(0.05,0.1]  20          7
(0.05,0.1]  21          2
(0.05,0.1]  11          1
(0.1,0.15]  20          2
(0.1,0.15]  21          1
(0.15,0.2]  20          2
(0.15,0.2]  21          1
(0.3,0.35]  20          2
(0.35,0.4]  20          2
(0.45,0.5]  20          2
(0.55,0.6]  20          1
(0.6,0.65]  20          1 """

d = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep="\s+").reset_index()
```

The steps to perform the calculations:

1) [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `index`

2) select data with needed `rate`

3) divide by sum within group

Code:

```
rate = 20

d.groupby("index").apply(lambda x:
    x.loc[x["rate"] == rate, "a.status"] / x["a.status"].sum())
```

Result:

```
index         
(0.0,0.05]  0     1.000000
(0.05,0.1]  1     0.700000
(0.1,0.15]  4     0.666667
(0.15,0.2]  6     0.666667
(0.3,0.35]  8     1.000000
(0.35,0.4]  9     1.000000
(0.45,0.5]  10    1.000000
(0.55,0.6]  11    1.000000
(0.6,0.65]  12    1.000000
```